# Codeigniter - Search form with multiple parameters

Tags: php, codeigniter

Basically this code functions by pulling data entered by the user in the form and connects to the model which performs a query search based on the inputted information.

This code works but it only works when i enter both the $no and $first fields. But i need it to work so the user will be able to enter the $no and leave the other variable empty.

I thought i could use some sort of OR statement but i'm unsure how to implement it. Any help would be appreciated and i apologize if its not clear enough i'm fairly new when it comes to codeigniter.

Controller

```
    public function query()

{

    $no = $this->input->post('no');
    $first = $this->input->post('first');
    $this->load->model("test");
         $data['query']=$this->test->query($no,$first);
        $this->load->view('query',$data);

}
```

Model

```
function query($no, $first)
{

 return $query = $this->db->get_where('table', array('no' => $no,
 'first' => $first ))->result();

}
```

View

```
<?php foreach($query as $row): ?>
<tr> 
    <td><?php echo $row->no; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row->date; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row->first; ?></td>


    </tr>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: check weather both variables are not empty and then do your query or change query accordingly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about just skipping any parameters that weren't provided?

```
function query($no, $first)
{
  $where = array();

  if ($no != '') $where['no'] = $no;
  if ($first != '') $where['first'] = $first;

  if (empty($where))
  {
    return array(); // ... or NULL
  }
  else
  {
    return $query = $this->db->get_where('table', $where);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For example

```
if(strlen($no)>0 && strlen($first)>0){
   $data['query']=$this->test->query($no,$first);
}else{
   $data['query']=$this->test->query($no);//or $first
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do using default parameter concept. can check user is passing both parameter or not accordingly you can call model and can send arguments.

Considering your example I am writing the code:

Controller

```
public function query()
{

$no = $this->input->post('no');
if($this->input->post('first'))
  $first = $this->input->post('first');
$this->load->model("test");
if($first != '')
  $data['query']=$this->test->query($no,$first);
else
  $data['query']=$this->test->query($no);
$this->load->view('query',$data);
}
```

Model

```
function query($no, $first = null)
{

 return $query = $this->db->get_where('table', array('no' => $no,
 'first' => $first ))->result();

}
```

View

```
<?php foreach($query as $row): ?>
<tr> <td><?php echo $row->no; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row->date; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row->first; ?></td>
</tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Using this concept you can use the same function in different places.
eg. you made search function with two diff. parameter for searching but using default parameter concept you can use the same function for searching the db with one or with both the parameters.

I hope I helped you! :)